# Click on Image button in IE

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am working on a project ''Automation IE'' but got stucked at clicking on Image button ...

I am trying to spool one excel report from website and for the same i need to click on Generate button ``` (type="submit")`` then one message will appear ```(Report Spooled Successfully)`then only I can click on download button`(type="image")`

**Screenshot**

[image: Below is the Screenshot]

**Below is generate button HTML source code**

```
<td align="right">
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnGenerate" value=" Generate "
onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnGenerate&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" 
id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnGenerate" tabindex="4" title="Click Here" class="dxbButton_Glass">
</td>
```

**Below is the HTML source code for message**

```
<td colspan="2">
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg" style="color:Blue;font-weight:bold;">Report Spooled Successfully</span>
</td>
```

**Below is The HTML source code for download button (`type="image"`)**

```
<td align="right" visible="false">
click here to Download&nbsp;
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkDownload" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload" tabindex="7" title="Download" src="../../Images/save.gif" alt="Download" style="border-width:0px;">
</td>
```

With my code i am able to click on `Generate` button but facing difficulty clicking on `Download` button after message appeared, have tried to looping until condition is met and tried if `Element.innertext = message` but no luck.

**Below is the My VBA code**

```
Sub KBOSS_Brokerage_Process_Status()
    Set Browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    Browser.Visible = false
    Browser.navigate ("my url")
    Set mymsg = Browser.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg")
    For Each elem In mymsg.getElementsByTagName("span")
        If elem.innerText = " Report Spooled Successfully " Then Exit For
    Next elem
    Browser.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload").Click
    Browser.Quit
    Set Browser = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Cross Post: 
https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/vba-code-to-select-an-option-from-html-drop-down-using-value-rather-than-index.37707/#post-228291

Comment: where is the code to click Generate button? what I understand that you have to wait after clicking Generate in a time bound loop for `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload` to appear and then only click it

Comment: What does no luck mean? You don't need a loop as you have an id for each element.

Comment: Hi, I am unsure how you can have that error on that line. Can you split into two lines  If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub : If testValue  <> "Report Spooled Successfully"   Then Exit Sub ...... and tell me if the error occurs on the first of those lines?

Comment: Hi  QHarr, i have edited as you mentioned in earlier comment and didn't got any error but clicking on download button is not happening..  **Browser.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload").Click**

Comment: **testValue = ele.innerText** is coming empty

Comment: Try stepping through with F8 going line by line using side by side screen view.

Comment: Hi QHarr, Sorry for late reply...i was gone out of station with limited internet access.  Thanks for the response.  i have tried step by step and didn't got any error but at the same time  **testValue = ele.innerText**  is showing nothing so **Browser.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload").Click** code is not executing..

Comment: Browser.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload").FireEvent "onclick"

Comment: Hi QHarr, this code is working but clicking the button before the ** Report Spooled Successfully**  message appears `Browser.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload").Click`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this may not solve your problems but at least it introduces proper waits for page loading, including after each click event, and a timed loop for the text you are after to appear. I also add a commented out FireEvent in case that is needed to trigger the `onclick`. You don't need to set `Browser` to nothing. It will be disposed of when the sub completes. When the Object variable releases its reference by going out of scope  the runtime calls the target object’s [Release](https://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-whats-in-a-variable/) method to decrement the object’s reference count.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub KbossBrokerageProcessStatus()
    Dim browser As Object, t As Date, ele As Object, testValue As String
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5

    Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With browser
        .Visible = True
        .navigate2 "myUrl"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document

            .getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnGenerate").Click '.FireEvent("onclick")

            While browser.Busy Or browser.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Do
                DoEvents
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = .getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg")
                testValue = ele.innerText
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While testValue  <> "Report Spooled Successfully"

            If ele Is Nothing Or testValue  <> "Report Spooled Successfully"   Then Exit Sub

            .document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload").Click

            While browser.Busy Or browser.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        End With

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Devendra, I can see that you had deleted your previous comment. I made a test with the code suggested by QHarr and it is working fine. I suggest you to again make a test and comment about your testing result. It can help us to get the idea about current status of your issue.